# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from setting pass-by-writeback error within enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

The following code causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` upon attempting to set `*error`.

```objectivec
- (void)triggerEXC_BAD_ACCESS
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self doSetErrorInBlock:&error];
}

- (void)doSetErrorInBlock:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
    [@[@(0)] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"some.domain" code:100 userInfo:nil]; // <--- causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }];
}
```

However, I'm not sure why the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is occurring.

Replacing the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` call with the following function, which tries to reproduce the function signature of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, will let the function `triggerEXC_BAD_ACCESS` run without error:

```objectivec
- (void)doSetErrorInBlock:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
    [self runABlock:^(id someObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *anotherWriteback) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"some.domain" code:100 userInfo:nil]; // <--- No crash here
    }];
}

- (void)runABlock:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
{
    BOOL anotherWriteback = NO;
    block(@"Some string", 0, &anotherWriteback);
}
```

Not sure if I'm missing anything about how ARC works here, or if it's specific to the version of Xcode that I'm using (Xcode 12.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce a crash in `-doSetErrorInBlock:`, but I can reproduce a crash in `-triggerEXC_BAD_ACCESS` with "-[NSError retain]: message sent to deallocated instance" in debug node (I am not sure if it's due to NSZombie or some other debug options).

The reason for it is that `*error` in `-doSetErrorInBlock:` has type `NSError * __autoreleasing`, and the implementation of `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]` (which is closed-source but it's possible to examine the assembly) happens to internally have an autorelease pool around the execution of the block. An object pointer which is `__autoreleasing` means that we don't retain it, and we assume it is alive by being retained by some autorelease pool. That means it is bad to assign something to an `__autoreleasing` variable inside an autorelease pool, and then try to access it after the autorelease pool ended, because the end of the autorelease pool could have deallocated it, so you can be left with a dangling pointer. [This section](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#storage-duration-of-autoreleasing-objects) of the ARC spec says:

> It is undefined behavior if a non-null pointer is assigned to an
> `__autoreleasing` object while an autorelease pool is in scope and
> then that object is read after the autorelease pool’s scope is left.

The reason why the crash message says it is trying to retain it, is because of what happens when you try to pass a "pointer to `__strong`" (e.g. `&error` in `-triggerEXC_BAD_ACCESS`) to a parameter of type "pointer to `__autoreleasing`" (e.g. the parameter of `-doSetErrorInBlock:`). As you can see from [this section](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#passing-to-an-out-parameter-by-writeback) of the ARC spec, a "pass-by-writeback" process happens, where they create a temporary variable of type `__autoreleasing`, assign the value of the `__strong` variable to it, make the call, and then assign the value of the `__autoreleasing` variable back to the `__strong` variable, so your `triggerEXC_BAD_ACCESS` method is really kind of like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSError * __autoreleasing temporary = error;
[self doSetErrorInBlock:&temporary];
error = temporary;
```

The last step of assigning the value back to the `__strong` variable performs a retain, and that's when it encounters the deallocated instance.

I could reproduce the same crash in your second example if I change the `-runABlock:` to:

```
- (void)runABlock:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
{
    BOOL anotherWriteback = NO;
    @autoreleasepool {
        block(@"Some string", 0, &anotherWriteback);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't really use `__autoreleasing` in a new method that you write. `__strong` is much better because the strong reference makes sure you don't accidentally have dangling references and problems like that. The main reason why `__autoreleasing` exists is because back in manual reference counting days, there were no explicit ownership qualifiers, and the "convention" was that retain counts were not transferred into or out of methods, and so objects returned from a method (including objects returned by pointer using an out-parameter) would be autoreleased rather than retained. (And those methods would be responsible for ensuring that the object is still valid when the method returns.) And since your program can be used on different OS versions, they cannot change the behavior of APIs in new OS versions, so they are stuck with this "pointer to `__autoreleasing`" type. However, in a method that you yourself write in ARC (which does have explicit ownership qualifiers), which is only going to be called by your own ARC code, by all means use `__strong`. If you wrote your method using `__strong`, it would not crash ([by default](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters) pointer-to-object-pointers are interpreted as `__autoreleasing`, so you have to specify `__strong` explicitly):

```
- (void)doSetErrorInBlock:(NSError * __strong *)error
{
    [@[@(0)] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"some.domain" code:100 userInfo:nil];
    }];
}
```

If you for some reason insist on taking a parameter of type `NSError * __autoreleasing *`, and want to do the same thing you were doing but safely, you should be using a `__strong` variable for the block, and only assign it into the `__autoreleasing` at the end:

```
- (void)doSetErrorInBlock:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
    __block NSError *result;
    [@[@(0)] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        result = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"some.domain" code:100 userInfo:nil];
    }];
    *error = result;
}
```